The number of values of a nested radical expression
It seems that when a multivalued function is used multiple times in an expression, it is taken to have the same branch in each.
$$\sqrt{i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
The principal value of $\sqrt{2}$ gives the principal value of $\sqrt{i}$, and vice versa. We can't mix and match though. If we try to say the real part uses the principal root and the imaginary part uses the other root, we get a value of $\sqrt{-i}$ instead.
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^{2}}=\tan^{-1}(1)-\tan^{-1}(0)$$
It doesn't matter which branch we use, as long as it's the same for both.
$$\tan^{-1}(1)-\tan^{-1}(0)=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}-k\pi=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
Knowing this, what about infinitely nested radicals? An example is this:
$$\sqrt{i\sqrt{i\sqrt{i\sqrt{...}}}}$$
This is the limit of the sequence $\sqrt{i\sqrt{i\sqrt{...\sqrt{i}}}}$ where $n$ copies of $i$ appear. These square roots actually make different functions - the second $i$ is impacted by a fourth root, for example. It can be simplified to $i^{\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}}$ which is $2^{n}$ valued because $\gcd(2^{n}-1,2^{n})=1$
Let $n\to\infty$ and the number of values of the limit is infinite, with principal value $i$
But what of another result?
$$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{...}}}}$$
The principal value is $3$, but how many other values are there? Last time, the many square roots made different functions with more values, but this time I don't see such a simplification, thanks to the addition embedded within. Does this mean every single root is necessarily on the same branch, giving only two values? Let $\sqrt{1}=1$, then the other value can be expressed as
$$-\sqrt{1-2\sqrt{1-3\sqrt{1-4\sqrt{...}}}}$$
Is that right? Is that the only other possible value, or are we allowed to make some positive and others negative? As a bonus I suppose, what is that other one equal to?
